# AngularJs combined date & time picker

Tags: angularjs

I am looking for something which combines [Angular Ui Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)'s DatePicker and TimePicker.

When I place them side by side, the look ugly, no matter what I do with CSS.

Besides, I would rather get the properties of one ng-model than of two.

---

[Update] here's an example from my own answer below. Unfortunately, I can't get that working with eh framework which I use :-(

Does anyone know of something similar?  I would rather have one icon than two, for use on smaller screens.

[image: Calender Date Picker UI]

when you click "time", the calendar is replaced by
[image: Time Picker UI]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, just in case it helps anyone else in future, I finally found [Bootstrap-UI/datetime-picker](https://github.com/Gillardo/bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker), you can check out the demo at http://plnkr.co/edit/S8UqwvXNGmDcPXV7a0N3?p=preview